# How do I get the primary site URL?

Tags: multi-site, siteurl

Is there an available variable for the primary site URL in a multi-site CraftCMS setup? I need a variable that I can attach to my logo that will take the user back to the primary site. I could hard code this, however, the URL needs to be environment aware. For example, on my local environment, the link should be https://www.mysite.local and when on development, the link should be https://www.mysite.dev.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can output the primary site’s Base URL like this:

```twig
{{ craft.app.sites.primarySite.baseUrl }}
```

(`craft.app.sites` maps to [craft\services\Sites](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-sites.html).)

If your Base URL begins with an [alias](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/#aliases), you will need to parse it:

```twig
{{ alias(craft.app.sites.primarySite.baseUrl) }}
```

Altertatively, if you need to link to a sub-page of the primary site (not just its Base URL), you can do that with the [siteUrl()](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/functions.html#siteurl-path-params-scheme-siteid) function, which has a `siteId` argument.

```twig
{% set primary = craft.app.sites.primarySite %}
{{ siteUrl('sub/path', siteId=primary.id) }}
```

Note that if your primary site’s Base URL contains the `@web` alias, that will always just return the host info for the current request. So you may need to replace that with a hard-coded base URL (or use a custom [alias](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/#aliases)) before this works as expected.

Comment: This also gives the URL of the site I'm on, not the default site in a multi-site installation. The default site in my multi-site installation is www, and I have 5 subdomains. So, when I'm on blog.mysite.com and I use url(), I get blog.mysite.com -- this is not what I'm looking for. What I really want is www.mysite.com -- the default site in the multi-site installation.

Comment: @VaughnD.Taylor Sorry, misunderstood your question. By “default” I take it you meant the primary site. Updated your question and my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`{{ siteUrl }}` should do the trick for you.

Comment: This gives the URL of the site I'm on, not the default site in a mult-site installation.